# Set flex item height to size of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs in a column. Each div has content that should scroll if it overflows. I would like each div to have the same height, with the max height of each div to be the height of its content. Is this possible to implement using flexbox?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6puccbh/2/

As you can see in the fiddle, all three sections are the same height, but I would like the middle section to be only as tall as its content.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content
            <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
            <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content
            <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
            <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
height: 300px;
}

.panel {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.section {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But without any code from you we can't help. Please learn how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, I added an example.

Comment: @Terry Any ideas? I'm wondering if this is even possible using only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
height: fit-content;
```

Can you use link:
https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <p>content sjkdkjasdn asjn dvas jkdb ajd avsd</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.section:nth-child(2) {
    height:unset;
}

p {
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}
```

[here's a fork of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfpd8erc/)

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I would like all the sections to be the same height, only up to the height of the content. Please see the example I added.

Comment: I get it now... Sorry but there was no example before.